# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 : Unable to bind portable JNDI name error

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I am doing web-logic 10.3 migration to web-logic 12.2.1.3 while starting server I am facing below issue 
JDK-8

```
<Oct 18, 2018 3:42:26,465 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to 
 set the activation state to true for the application "sbcacrm_deploy_jar".
 weblogic.application.ModuleException: Unable to bind portable JNDI name 
 java:global/sbcacrm_deploy/corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFM. NestedException Message 
 is :null
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:123)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:207)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

ejb.xml:

```
 <session>
 <description> Management EJB</description> 
  <ejb-name>corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFM</ejb-name>
  <home>corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFMBusinessAPIHome</home>
  <remote>corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFMBusinessAPI</remote>
  <ejb-class>corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFMBusinessAPIBean</ejb-class>
  <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
  <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
</session>
```

web-ejb.xml:

```
<weblogic-enterprise-bean>
<ejb-name>corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFM</ejb-name>
<stateless-session-descriptor>
  <pool>
  </pool>
  <stateless-clustering>
    <home-is-clusterable>False</home-is-clusterable>
    <stateless-bean-is-clusterable>False</stateless-bean-is-clusterable>
  </stateless-clustering>
</stateless-session-descriptor>
<transaction-descriptor>
<trans-timeout-seconds>300</trans-timeout-seconds>
</transaction-descriptor>
<enable-call-by-reference>True</enable-call-by-reference>
<jndi-name>corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFMBusinessAPIHome</jndi-name>
</weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at weblogic server's logs to see why it fails to deploy you EJB.

Comment: Yes ,but i can see same error in log

Comment: <BEA-014022> <corp.acrm.ots.API.OTSBusinessAPIHome is bound with JNDI name java:module/corp.acrm.ots.API!corp.acrm.ots.API.OTSBusinessAPIHome.> 
BEA-011061> <Stack trace associated with message Error activating EJB: corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFM follows: 

Unable to bind portable JNDI name java:global/sbcacrm_deploy/corp.acrm.fin.API.OLFM. NestedException Message is :null
 at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.Ejb2JndiBinder.pickAndBindInGlobalNS(Ejb2JndiBinder.java:140)